# Why does my reducer parameter type accepts `undefined`?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, redux-actions

I am using `typescript` in my react/redux app. There is a type error I don't understand.

Below is my action code:

```
import { createAction } from 'redux-actions';

export enum ProductActionType {
  SEARCH_STAMP = 'SEARCH_STAMP',
  SEARCH_PRODUCT = 'SEARCH_PRODUCT',
};

export interface ProductActionProps {
  text: string;
}

const searchStamp = createAction<ProductActionProps>(ProductActionType.SEARCH_STAMP);
```

Below is my reducer:

```
import { handleActions } from 'redux-actions';
import { ProductActionType, ProductActionProps } from '@ap-actions/index';

export const productReducer = handleActions<Product, ProductActionProps>(
  {
    [ProductActionType.SEARCH_STAMP]: (state, { payload }) => { // here why payload type is ProductActionProps | undefined?
      ...
    }
  }, initialState
);
```

The issue is about the `payload` type inside `handleActions`. Its type is `ProductActionProps | undefined`. I have to check whether `payload` is `undefined` in the body of the function. But I don't understand why the type accepts `undefined`?

Comment: Did you install types for `redux-actions`? How did you install those types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right that the type of `{ payload }` should be `{ ProductActionProps }`. I am wondering about the type definitions that you have installed for `redux-actions`.

If you haven't already, install the `redux-actions` type declarations.

```
npm install @types/redux-actions --save-dev
```

Then restart your editor (in order to restart the TypeScript language service).

If that still doesn't work, you might need to upgrade your types. I am using `"@types/redux-actions": "^2.6.1"` which does not reproduce your error.